# Append to jquery javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript code in my main file and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.crBasketItems = [];
    window.crInvalidateCache = '{url module=frontend controller=StockAjax action=invalidateCache}';
    {foreach from=$sBasket.content item=basketItem}
        window.crBasketItems.push({$basketItem.articleID});
    {/foreach}
</script>
```

...but I would like to append a new javascript code (from another file) to the code. I can use a jQuery. How to?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.crPickwareHook = '{url module=frontend controller=clearShipped action=index}';
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It sounds like an X-Y problem. It would be better to explain why you need to set those properties.

Comment: Make the code a .js file (without the `<script type=`) and include it as a script `<script src="your_file.js"></script>`.